# Send data from a component to another component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have seen multiple same question then this one but I do not understand their answers.

i have a component that does a fetch and gets some data. I want to send this data with other informations to another componer (child? I don't really understand this).

here is my first component: (login.component.jsx)
I would like to pass IP, Username, password, CPGlist to the component in CreateVolume and use it over there.

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            IP: "xxx",
            username: "",
            password: "",
            submitted: false,
            CPGlist: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
.
.
.
    render() {
            const { IP, username, password, CPGlist, submitted } = this.state;
            if (submitted) {
                return (
                    <div>
                         < CreateVolume />
                    </div>
                );
            }
```

CreateVolume.component.jsx:

```
class CreateVolume extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            IP: "",
            username: "",
            password: "",
            submitted: false,
            name: "",
            cpg: "",
            size: "",
            unit: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
.
.
.
//some code
```

I should be able to get the IP/username/password/CPGlist from login.component.jsx into the CreateVolume.component.jsx

Thank you

Comment: Instead of `< CreateVolume />` replace it with `< CreateVolume  ip={ IP } password={ password } username={ username } cpgList= { CPGlist } />`

And in `CreateVolume` component you will have the data passed as props, available at `this.props`.

Comment: thank you for this aswer. I will try this

Comment: this.state = {
            IP: "",
            username: "",
            password: "",


Do I need to let this in the CreateVolume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class CreateVolume extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        IP: this.props.data.Id,
        username:  props.data.username,
        password: props.data.password,
        submitted: props.data.submitted,
        name: "",
        cpg: "",
        size: "",
        unit: ""

    };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }
}


class Login extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        IP: "xxx",
        username: "",
        password: "",
        submitted: false,
        CPGlist: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
      render() {
        const data = this.state;
        if (submitted) {
            return (
                <div>
                     < CreateVolume  data={data}/>
                </div>
              );
         }
```

passing state as props to child!

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your detailed answer. I did exacly what you did. To call the IP in the CreateVolume for exemple I do like this :  ```<p>{this.props.IP}</p>```, any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: the props here is data so this.props.data.IP !

Answer (score 1):

Mount `<CreateVolume />` only if data in state is populated.

```
{
    this.state.ip && this.state.ip!="" &&
    <CreateColume
        IP = {this.state.IP}
        ...
    />
}
```

Comment: You can also pass data which you extracted  from state in render() function.